# Multiple form validation in PageView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have forms inside PageView, one unique form on each page, and i need to validate them all. So i wrote that code...

```
PageView.builder(
   contoller: controller,
   itemCount: pageValues.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Form(
         key: formKeys[index]
         child: Column(
            TextFormField(
                controller: someController,
                validator: (value) => value.isEmpty
                   ? "Enter something"
                   : null
            )
         )
      )
   }
)
```

I store form keys inside growable list, so when I add a new page my list of form keys expands with new *GlobalKey<FormState>()*

I have button to validate all forms

```
Button(
    onPressed: () {
        if(formKeys.every((element) => element.currentState.validate())){
            some actions...
        }
    }
)
```

So when I press button i get this exception

```
The method 'validate' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: validate()
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to print currentState of each key and saw this in console:

```
I/flutter (30149): null
I/flutter (30149): FormState#84571
```

I have two pages and currently i'm on the second page but if i go to the first page and again print currentState i get this:

```
I/flutter (30149): FormState#65c3d
I/flutter (30149): null
```

So now i need to know how to save or persist states of my form keys when i switch pages.

[Screenshot of widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWqUq.jpg)